# AWS IAM: BOTO3: Unable to assume role across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

not sure if title made sense.

I have a python service on a kubernetes pod in account A, that needs to assume role in account B.

The error I get is:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::accountA:assumed-role/worker_role/botocore-session-123456 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/target_role
```

The accout B trust relationship for `arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/target_role` is setup this way:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::accountA:role/worker_role"
                ]
             },
             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
```

and the trust relationship for `arn:aws:iam::accountA:role/worker_role` is:

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::accountA:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/clusterID"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/clusterID:sub": "system:serviceaccount:k8s_serviceaccount_name"
```

So essentially, I can't see what I've done wrong here. From what I can tell, my kubernetes pod on my cluster is correctly assuming the `worker_role` in accountA, as that shows up in the error message (and an STS get caller identity call), and the trust relationship shows that it should be able to assume `target_role` in accountB.

My only thought is that it comes across as `assumed-role/worker_role/botocore-session-123456` as the identity, and not `worker_role`.

Otherwise I'm stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role-A also requires permission to call `AssumeRole` on Role-B. This must be added as a policy in Role-A itself (much like you would give it permission to access an S3 bucket).

The policy would look something like:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/target_role"
  }
}
```